# getDatecreated in Appps Script returning the time of creation an hour later

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, time, google-drive-api

When I try to get the time of creation of a file in Google Drive with the built in function getDateCreated() in the apps script, it returns the time an hour after the creation.
My code is as follows

```
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(myFolderId);

  var contents = folder.getFiles();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  var var_file;
  var var_name;
  var var_link;
  var var_owner;
  var var_time;

  while(contents.hasNext()){
    var_file = contents.next();
    var_name = var_file.getName();
    var_link = var_file.getUrl();
    var_owner = var_file.getOwner().getName();
    var_time = var_file.getDateCreated();
    sheet.appendRow([var_name,var_link,var_owner, var_time]);
  }
```

If time of creation of a file is 25/06/2022 22:48:39
The output of my code returns 25/06/2022 23:48:39 which is an error.
Note: My time zone is UTC-5

Comment: What is the value of `var_time.getTime()`?

Answer (score 1):

I did some research on different built-in methods in Javascript and the `.toLocaleTimeString()` seems to work fine returning the actual time the file was created.

```
var_time = var_file.getDateCreated().toLocaleTimeString();
```

It's also quite important to check the appsscript.json file which can be accesed by going to Project Settings and toggling on the option Show the appsscripts.json file

Answer (score 0):

The only reason could be the time zone setup of your script file. You can check out bi going to **File > Project properties** in the script editor.

[Google developers docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getscripttimezone)

Also you can review this setting running this:

```
var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
Logger.log(timeZone);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I checked and the time zone of the script is the same as my time zone.  Maybe it's a bug or something about my PC and the time configurated in it.
I'll try on another computer and keep this updated